# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when using Hibernate

Tags: java, exception, servlets, jboss5.x

I'm trying to store data to MySql server local installation using hibernate, via a jsp/servlet web app.

what i did was i first tried and succeed using a standalone java application, then in the same project i added a web module and copied the working code.

i got the following error when i deployed my web app to jboss 5,

```
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    org.hibernate.mapping.Table.setSchema(Table.java:643)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings.addTable(Mappings.java:191)
    org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:312)
    org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:295)
    org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:166)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:702)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:537)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:599)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1621)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1589)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1568)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1448)
    com.directfn.backend.servlet.PersistanceServlet.doGet(PersistanceServlet.java:46)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

can some one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I would pay attention to the line: org.hibernate.mapping.Table.setSchema(Table.java:643) Perhaps DB schema isn't configured well or even isn't specified.

Comment: Debug it and post the output. That will tell you on which mapping file it is choking.

Comment: what i did was i first tried and succeed using a standalone java application, then in the same project i added a web module and copied the working code. how can the DB schema isn't configured well or even isn't specified then??

Comment: I see only the stack trace you have posted previously and the last instruction where the exception has been thrown. I don't know how you have "copied" the working code. Perhaps the server uses another encoding for configuration files.

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in your hibernate xml file.

for ex. "test.hbm.xml"

This exception occur when read hibernate mapping file.
May be you have set column name or property name blank or null.

`<property name="" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name=""></column>
</property>`

set proper name of property/column.